# Multiple Marker Types for one Function

Tags: matlab, plot

I am using the `plot3c` function to map a matrix of data in the x,y,z, and color axes.  For clarification, my z-data and color data are one and the same, but represented on the two axes. Due to instrumental limitations, my data has a set of false color values where an unreadable point is represented with a 0.  I would like to have every z/color value of 0 represented with a different marker type than the rest of the data.  I know how to change marker type for a plot but I do not know how to set a marker type for specific values within a plot.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just overlay a second plot that only plots where `z` is `0`:

```
% Your original plot, I'm assuming plot3c(x,y,z,z)

hold on

mask = z==0;
plot3(x(mask), y(mask), z(mask), '^')
```

Or more efficiently as suggested in radarhead's comment:

```
mask = z==0;
plot3c(x(~mask), y(~mask), z(~mask), z(~mask))
hold on
plot3(x(mask), y(mask), z(mask), '^')
```

Comment: I would also suggest using the same mask to plot only non-zero elements at first. That way you won't have two markers on those zero elements.